# Bash: "No such file or directory" despite directory existing

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am making a custom command that moves or duplicates a file to a wastebasket directory instead of deleting it. I am trying to make a directory if it already isn't there, make a duplicate if a file has already been executed on, and simply move it if it doesn't. The issue is that I keep getting a no such file or directory error regardless of where I place the wastebasket directory. Do note that simply moving or copying the file with base linux commands work fine, and that being in root doesn't fix the issue. What steps should I take?

```
    #!/bin/bash
set -x
        mkdir -p /home/WASTEBASKIT #This makes a wastebasket directory if it doesn't already exist.
        if test -e "$1"; then 
                    if  test -e /home/WASTEBASKIT/"$1"; then #Checking for duplicate files.
                    cp "$1" "/home/WASTEBASKIT/$1.$$"
                 else
                    mv "$1" "/home/WASTEBASKIT"
                fi
        else
            printf '%s\n' "File not found." #Error if a file is not there.
            fi
```

Here are the results: ++ mkdir -p /home/WASTEBASKIT

++ test -e config.sh

++ test -e /home/WASTEBASKIT/config.sh

++ cp config.sh.945 ' /home/WASTEBASKIT'

cp: cannot stat 'config.sh.945': No such file or directory

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in `cp "$1" "$1.$$" "/home/WASTEBASKIT"`?

Comment: It gives an alternate file name so that the original disposed file isn't overwritten.

Comment: Yeah the changes makes it work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cp config.sh.945 ' /home/WASTEBASKIT'
> cp: cannot stat 'config.sh.945': No such file or directory
> ```

The problem is on this line:

```
cp "$1" "$1.$$" "/home/WASTEBASKIT"
```

You try to copy *two* files into `/home/WASTEBASKIT`, namely `$1` and `$1.$$`. The latter does not exist.

Change it to:

```
cp "$1" "/home/WASTEBASKIT/$1.$$"
```

I suggest that you instead create a unique file since process numbers aren't unique, so instead of the copy above, do something like:

```
newfile=$(mktemp "WASTEBASKIT/$1.XXXXXXX")
cp -p "$1" "$newfile"
```

You can then list all the copies with `ls -t WASTEBASKIT` to get them in historical order, newest first - or with `ls -tr WASTEBASKIT` to get the oldest first.

Also note: `printf'%s\n' "File not found."` will likely generate an error like `printf%s\n: command not found...`. You need to insert a space between the command `printf` and the argument `'%s\n'`.

The moving part is also wrong since you have a space before `/home`. It should be:

```
mv "$1" /home/WASTEBASKIT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mv "$1" " /home/WASTEBASKIT"
```

First issue: spaces matter. If you have previously created the `/home/WASTEBASKIT` directory, and then execute that copy command above, it will *not* copy the file into that directory - you will most likely end up with a *file* in your home directory called `spaceWASTEBASKIT` (unless you already have a directory of that name, including the leading space) in which case it will go into that directory.

Either way, it won't go where you want it to go.

Secondly, the command below is not doing what you seem to think. It will try to copy two files to the directory, the second of which probably does not even exist (`config.sh.945` in your case):

```
cp "$1" "$1.$$" "/home/WASTEBASKIT"
```

If you want to create a "uniquely" versioned file so as to not overwrite an existing one, that would be:

```
mv "$1" "/home/WASTEBASKIT/$1.$$"
```

Note the quotes around the word "uniquely" since there's no guarantee `$1.$$` may not *also* exist in the wastebasket - the PIDs do eventually wrap around at some point, and also do so on reboot.

I suspect a better approach (though still not bullet-proof) would be just to prefix every file with the date and time so that:

- you can sort duplicates to establish the order of creation; and
- sans date changes, the date/time *won't* give you possible duplicates (unless you're doing it more then once per second).

That approach would be something like:

```
mv "$1" "/home/WASTEBASKIT/$(date -u +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)$1"
```

or, making duplicates even *less* likely:

```
mv "$1" "/home/WASTEBASKIT/$(date -u +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_${RANDOM}_$1"
```